# MECM Brosix Application Installer

Tags: installation, sccm, unattended-processing

I am running into an issue when trying to add Brosix as an application to MECM for quick and easy deployment upon imaging of a laptop. This requires the Brosix installer to run in unattended mode (aka silently/quietly) but I cannot find such a command when running the installer and I am also planning on running their installer with the /advanced command so that it installs for all users instead of a singular one. So far /silent has not worked for me and neither has /unattended when running these installers in cmd or Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Brosix did not make support for silent or unattended installs using their advanced installer which installs for all users, although I was unable to confirm this from Brosix despite calling them and making a support ticket. Therefore, it seems the solution for MECM is to have it be a per-user install (that is silent normally) which is something you need to set up when you build it in MECM.